# C# WPF Login System with CSV File

Tags: c#, wpf, csv

I am trying to create a basic login system using C# WPF which links to a csv file holding the details.

My CSV file looks like this:

id ,username,password,firstname,surname,email
1,ashleigh,password ,ashleigh,halliday,ashleigh@email.com
2,user,password ,user,user,user@email.com

I am trying to verify that the username and passwords match. I am using a standard text box for the username and a password box in WPF for the password.

I have done some research and when I display what has been stored in each variable (depending on what the user has entered for their username and password), they match what I have stored in the CSV file. I have also included constructors containing this.password = password; and using a { get; set; }

I am a little confused as I can verify that the username matches but it wont accept what the user has entered in the password box to match what is in the CSV file.

My code is:

```
private void ClickLogin(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string username = EnterUsername.Text;
    string password = EnterPassword.Password;

    List<Login> login = new List<Login>();

    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\ashle\OneDrive\Documents\Uni\Level 5\Object Orientated Programming\Practical\CSV Files\login.csv"))
    {
        var header = reader.ReadLine();

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            Login l = new Login();

            l.Username = values[1];
            l.Password = values[2];

            login.Add(l);
        }

        foreach (Login l in login)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("csv Username is " + l.Username);
            //MessageBox.Show("csv Password is " + l.Password);
            //MessageBox.Show("entered username is " + username);
            //MessageBox.Show("entered password is " + password);

            if (username == l.Username && password == l.Password)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have logged in");
                //direct to homepage
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect details, try again");
                //redirect user back to login
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is quite basic, and not the best way to do things but can anyone see any issues with why the password wont be accepted and match what is in my CSV file. Thank you :)

Comment: Sounds like some pretty straightforward debugging should solve this.  Are you using Visual Studio?  If so, when you debug and look at the values `username` and `password` in the Debugger "Watch" window, do they match `l.Username` and `l.Password`?

Comment: Agree with @Joe about debugging.  But a quick guess is that the logic in your `for` loop is strange.  It will show a MessageBox for every potential login from the CSV.   Probably you will want to separate the MessageBox calls from the `for` loop, and only show one message to the user after the entire loop has been checked.  (For example, `bool loginFound = false;` and then if a match was found, `loginFound = true; break;`

Comment: WPF and UWP were designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. This does not look like the MVVM pattern. While you can programm without it, you miss about 90% of the power and run into issues at every other corner. I wrote a short intro about 8 Years ago that I hope is sitll valid to get you started: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: You never want to store passwords in a CSV file so it is pointless to know how to do it. The security is very weak.

Comment: @Phil1970 I agree with most of your comment besides the comment, `it is pointless to know how to do it`, maybe OP is learning to work with IO operations, comparing data etc. who knows. Instead of a subtle *put-down*, could you explain why *its pointless and how the security is very weak* so you could help give reasoning to your comments and so the OP understands your concerns?

Comment: @zaggler Well, one has to carefully check the path of the password file to know that OP is learning (and not writing production code).

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop, you redirect to the fail page when you test the login details against the current row. So the loop will only do the first row, and then redirect if it is not a match. You should only redirect to the fail page after completing the loop and not finding a match at all.

It is possible there are additional issues with the conditional test. It will be case-sensitive, the way you have it, which is not the norm with usernames. It is safer to use .Equals() for string comparison, though I don't know if it is making a difference in this case.